# Export a table created in javascript to a pdf file without showing the table on page

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

I want to save data related to a particular user into a pdf file , this is to be done on button click and without displaying the table on the page , I am using jspdf for this ,

```
var div_cr= document.createElement("div");
div_cr.id="xdiv";
var Table_Pull = document.createElement("TABLE");
var header = Table_Pull.createTHead();
var row = header.insertRow(0);
var cell = row.insertCell(0);
cell.innerHTML = "Date";
var cell = row.insertCell(1);
cell.innerHTML = "Attitude";
var cell = row.insertCell(2);
cell.innerHTML = "DeadlineMet";
var cell = row.insertCell(3);
cell.innerHTML = "Discippline";

var row = Table_Pull.insertRow(-1);

var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
cell1.innerHTML="HEllo";

var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
cell2.innerHTML="Hi";

var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
cell3.innerHTML="Goodday";

var doc = new jsPDF();

var dvTable = document.getElementById("xdiv");
dvTable.appendChild(Table_Pull);


var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function(element, renderer){
        return true;
    }
};

doc.fromHTML($('#dvTable').get(0), 15, 15, {
    'width': 170,
    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
});
doc.save('Test.pdf');
```

the code above creates a div and table in javascript , adds data to the table and appends the table to the div and passes the div to the jspdf function to create a div.

I am getting the following error,

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
```

the code attempts to download the table data into a pdf file without actually displaying the table on page , it works fine if I append the table to a div created in html and then pass the div to the jspdf function but as I donot want to display the table on the page this is not the right way to achieve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made changes in your code, basically you can use the reference straight away.

```
var div_cr= document.createElement("div");
div_cr.id="xdiv";
var Table_Pull = document.createElement("TABLE");
var header = Table_Pull.createTHead();
var row = header.insertRow(0);
var cell = row.insertCell(0);
cell.innerHTML = "Date";
var cell = row.insertCell(1);
cell.innerHTML = "Attitude";
var cell = row.insertCell(2);
cell.innerHTML = "DeadlineMet";
var cell = row.insertCell(3);
cell.innerHTML = "Discippline";

var row = Table_Pull.insertRow(-1);

var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
cell1.innerHTML="HEllo";

var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
cell2.innerHTML="Hi";

var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
cell3.innerHTML="Goodday";

var doc = new jsPDF();

div_cr.appendChild(Table_Pull);


var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function(element, renderer){
        return true;
    }
};

doc.fromHTML(div_cr, 15, 15, {
    'width': 170,
    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
});
doc.save('Test.pdf');
```

Comment: yes the reference wasn't right just made the change